# What specific knowledge is purposefully held back by the universities from their students?

Tags: epistemology

I read a quote once that this is done as a grocer would hold back the knowledge of the second half of a punnet of strawberries being mouldy. I have my theories but was there a specific knowledge set being reffered to?

Comment: What is the link with pilosophy ? and with epistemology ?

Comment: I find it tremendously amusing that people are trying to close this question for being "too broad"... Colin: but the question isn't really "the best fit" on here, have a look in the help section for pointers (under how to ask). - Welcome to Philosophy SE!

Comment: If I bought a punnet of strawberries that was half mouldy I’d take it back and get it exchanged. I don’t quite see the connection with your question. One of the main critiques of universities is of their creeping corporatisation under the neoliberal regime over the last forty years.

Answer (score 2):

Ilan Pappe, the historian has criticised universities as ‘sites for careers’ rather than their ostensible purpose as the site for understanding and critique. This critique has been echoed by the Badiou.

That this is the case is, according to Chomsky, due to the argument put forward in the [Powell Memorandum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_F._Powell_Jr.#Powell_Memorandum) Lewis Powell before he joined the US Supreme Court. He argued:

> The most disquieting voices joining the chorus of criticism came from perfectly respectable elements of society: from the college campus, from the pulpit, the media, the intellectual & literary journals, the arts and sciences and from politicians.

One might think, of course, if those voices were coming from a substantial and respectable quarters then they should be take seriously as opposed to being marginalised. However, in the memorandum, Powell advocated

> ”Constant surveillance” of textbook and television content, as well as a purge of left-wing elements ... he urged conservatives to take a sustained media out-reach programme ... following the memos directives, conservatives foundations greatly increased, pouring money into think-tanks.

A large part of the effort was to find indirect means of pushing out young people entering studies and pursuing professions critical of the status quo; for example, by making courses of study prohibitively expensive.